# jcaptcha dependencies not available

Tags: repository, maven-dependency, jcaptcha

My legacy project is using jCaptcha libraries. While converting to that old project into a maven based project, I learned that jcaptcha is not available in any maven repository.

I am really shocked but wanted to ask if someone had faced the same issue in their projects or not and how they resolved this?

I know that the easy way out is to download the JAR and install that into the local repository but I believe in clean things, specially builds :)

Any help would be appreciated. I have gone through numerous maven repositories but in vain.

Thanks in advance.